# Redux - how to access the store "dispatch" after providing it with Provider?

Tags: redux

I have the following files:

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore(...)
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The `App` component: (App.js)

```
const App = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main))
export default App
```

So then how i can access `store.dispatch` inside of the `Main` component?
If i try to do it by `store.dispatch({...})` i get:

> 'store' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mapDispatchToProps looks like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    myAction1: () => dispatch(myAction1())
});

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

...then in the component, you can call `this.props.myAction1()`

If mapDispatchToProps uses [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators):

```
const actions = { myAction1, myAction2 };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
```

...then in the component, you can call `this.props.myAction1()` and `this.props.myAction2()`

If mapDispatchToProps is undefined:

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(Main)
```

then in the component, you can access  `this.props.dispatch`

Comment: My `mapDispatchToProps` looks like this: `function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

  return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)

}`

So how would i access it?

Comment: `bindActionCreators` creates props of the same name of the actions you pass in. See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

dispatch function should be available through this.props
    this.props.dispatch()

Answer (score 0):

Your component shouldn't access the store directly - `connect` abstracts that away.

Please see our new React-Redux docs page on [`connect`: Dispatching Actions with `mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/docs/using-react-redux/connect-dispatching-actions-with-mapdispatchtoprops) for a complete description of how to handle dispatching actions.